# Looking for the best tool to do large-scale set comparisons

Tags: database, architecture, lucene, set, scalability

I'm working on a project that requires finding the most intersected set among a great number of other sets.

That is, I have a large number (~300k) of sets with hundreds of entries each. Given one of the sets, I need to rank the other sets in order of how intersected they are. Additionally, the set entries contain properties which can be used as a filter, e.g. For set X, order the other sets by how much they intersect with the "green" entries subset.

I have free reign to architect this solution, and I'm looking for technology recommendations. I was initially thinking a relational DB would be the best suited, but I'm not sure how well it will perform doing these real time comparisons. Somebody recommended Lucene, but I'm not sure how well that would fit the bill.

I suppose it's worth mentioning that new sets will be added regularly and that the sets may grow, but never shrink.

Comment: FWIW, I've decided to go with a mixed strategy. Utilizing [Hibernate Search](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/search) to populate both an RDB backend and a Lucene index. The Lucene Documents will represent a high-level set, with no filtering criteria defined. Essentially, each Document will be a list of ID's.


The filtering will be done via the RDB. So for my hypothetical proposition above, the workflow would be as follows:


1)Query RDB to get the id of all "green" entries from set X     
2)Query Lucene with those id's to get a ranked result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are looking for: method, library, tool?

If you want to compute your large datasets really fast with distributed computing, you should check out [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce), e.g. using [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) on [Amazon EC2/S3 services](http://aws.amazon.com/de/ec2/).

Comment: Any of those would be great. That link eventually led me to [Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadoop). It sounds like it would be even easier to work with. Do you have an opinion on Hadoop as a "solution" to this problem?

Comment: I don't have any practical experience with it, but have read and heard a lot of praise for Hadoop! Also check out [here on stackoverflow][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hadoop]. You should know that Hadoop is open-source, MapReduce is patented by Google.

Comment: Oh, and in case you also like to learn while commuting: http://allthingshadoop.com/podcast/ is a nice hadoop podcast (and blog) that gives a lot of infos and insights.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene can easily scale to what you need. Solr will probably be easier to set up, and hadoop is most likely overkill for only a few million data points.

Something you need to think about is what definition of "how intersected" you want to use. If all the sets have the same size I suppose it's easy, but Jaccard distance might make more sense in other contexts; Lucene's default scoring is often good too.

My advice would be: try running the default Solr instance on your local workstation (it's a cllick-and-run jar type of deal). You'll know pretty quickly whether Solr/Lucene will work for you or if you'll have to custom code your own thing via Hadoop etc.